# loop post requests Scrapy

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm doing a scrapy spider where I have to send a loop of post requests to go to the next page, the problem is it only sends one post request. the querystring changes the element "currentPage" for each page, so I have to change the value of this key for each page and send the post. but, as I said before it stops after the first Post request.

[output scrapy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6TPU.png)

```
    import scrapy

    headers = {
        'accept': "*/*",
        'origin': "http://www.**********.com",
        'x-requested-with': "XMLHttpRequest",
        'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36",
        'referer': "http://www.**********.com/venta/",
        'accept-encoding': "gzip, deflate",
        'accept-language': "en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6",
        'cookie': "G_ENABLED_IDPS=google; cookieInterestedProject=416; visid_incap_434661=wjkf7tU+QPKDjpmWXz/BKSBz+1kAAAAAQUIPAAAAAAA7bs2fXOSL0JmeVSXo337M; incap_ses_223_434661=9zyRHwEdwGxtE8Ly00EYAxQw/VkAAAAAq7gkFJrJjsGdCgrRTwOfvg==; s_vnum=1512243236606%26vn%3D3; __utmz=other; s_cm=Natural%20Searchwww.google.com.co; s_v10=%5B%5B%27Natural%2520Search%27%2C%271509651236616%27%5D%2C%5B%27Natural%2520Search%27%2C%271509651249121%27%5D%2C%5B%27Natural%2520Search%27%2C%271509765142570%27%5D%2C%5B%27Natural%2520Search%27%2C%271509765184463%27%5D%5D; s_v8=%5B%5B%27natural%2520search%253A%2520google%253A%2520keyword%2520unavailable%27%2C%271509651236618%27%5D%2C%5B%27natural%2520search%253A%2520google%253A%2520keyword%2520unavailable%27%2C%271509651249123%27%5D%2C%5B%27natural%2520search%253A%2520google%253A%2520keyword%2520unavailable%27%2C%271509765142572%27%5D%2C%5B%27natural%2520search%253A%2520google%253A%2520keyword%2520unavailable%27%2C%271509765184465%27%5D%5D; ; s_cc=true; _ga=GA1.2.701497075.1509651237; _gid=GA1.2.1068485902.1509765143; NSC_nfuspdvbesbep-wt=ffffffff0975c87745525d5f4f58455e445a4a4229a2; OX_sd=1; OX_plg=pm; gpv_pn=metrocuadrado%3A%20buscar%3A%20resultados%20inmuebles%3A%20nuevo%20y%20usado; s_invisit=true; s_nr=1509765213941-Repeat; s_lv=1509765213944; s_lv_s=Less%20than%207%20days; s_sq=eltiempometrocuadradoprod%2Celtiempoglobal%3D%2526pid%253Dmetrocuadrado%25253A%252520buscar%25253A%252520resultados%252520inmuebles%25253A%252520nuevo%252520y%252520usado%2526pidt%253D1%2526oid%253Dhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.metrocuadrado.com%25252Fventa%25252F%252523%2526ot%253DA; madicionales=; mbarrio=; mciudad=; mgrupo=; mgrupoid=; mnrobanos=; mnrocuartos=; mnrogarajes=; msector=; mubicacion=; mvalorarriendo=; mzona=; orderBy=; selectedLocationCategory=; selectedLocationFilter=; sortType=; writtenFilters=mnrogarajes%3Bmnrobanos%3Bmnrocuartos%3Bmtiempoconstruido%3Bmarea%3Bmvalorarriendo%3Bmvalorventa%3Bmciudad%3Bmubicacion%3Bmtiponegocio%3Bmtipoinmueble%3Bmzona%3Bmsector%3Bmbarrio%3BselectedLocationCategory%3BselectedLocationFilter%3Bmestadoinmueble%3Bmadicionales%3BorderBy%3BsortType%3Bmestadoinmueble%3BcompanyType%3BcompanyName%3Bmidempresa%3Bmgrupo%3Bmgrupoid%3B; m2-srv=ffffffff0975c82e45525d5f4f58455e445a4a4229a2; mtiponegocio=venta; mtipoinmueble=; mvalorventa=; marea=; mtiempoconstruido=; companyType=; companyName=; midempresa=; mestadoinmueble=",
        'cache-control': "no-cache",
        'postman-token': "2e5f00b9-7c7c-32ed-1bdd-63cf2fed3cd8"
        }

    querystring = {
    "":"","mnrogarajes":"","mnrobanos":"","mnrocuartos":"","mtiempoconstruido":"","marea":"","mvalorarriendo":"","mvalorventa":"","mciudad":"","mubicacion":"","mtiponegocio":"venta","mtipoinmueble":"","mzona":"","msector":"","mbarrio":"","selectedLocationCategory":"","selectedLocationFilter":"","mestadoinmueble":"","madicionales":"","orderBy":"","sortType":"","companyType":"","companyName":"","midempresa":"","mgrupo":"","mgrupoid":"","currentPage":"2","totalPropertiesCount":"115747","totalUsedPropertiesCount":"113926","totalNewPropertiesCount":"1821","sfh":"1"
    }

    url = 'http://www.*******.com/search/list/ajax'
    num = 0

    class HouseseSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = "hoimom"
        start_urls = ['http://www.********.com/venta/']

        def parse(self,response):
            for num in range(2,100):
                for href in response.xpath('.//a[@class="data-details-id" and @itemprop="url"]/@href').extract():
                    yield scrapy.Request(url = href ,callback = self.parsei)
                querystring["currentPage"] = str(num)
                yield scrapy.Request(url = 'http://www.*********.com/search/list/ajax',method="POST",headers=headers,meta=querystring)



        def parsei(self, response):
            yield {
            'latitude': response.xpath('//input[@id="latitude"]/@value').extract(),
            'longitud': response.xpath('//input[@id="longitude"]/@value').extract(),
            'precio de arriendo': response.xpath('.//dl/dt[h3/text()="Valor de arriendo"]/following-sibling::dd[1]/h4/text()').extract_first(),
            'precio de venta': response.xpath('.//dl/dt[h3/text()="Valor de venta"]/following-sibling::dd[1]/h4/text()').extract_first(),
            'Barrio_com': response.xpath('.//dl/dt[h3/text()="Nombre com&uacute;n del barrio "]/following-sibling::dd[1]/h4/text()').extract_first(),
            'Barrio_cat': response.xpath('.//dl/dt[h3/text()="Nombre del barrio catastral"]/following-sibling::dd[1]/h4/text()').extract_first(),
            'Estrato': response.xpath('.//dl/dt[h3/text()="Estrato"]/following-sibling::dd[1]/h4/text()').extract_first(),
            'id': response.xpath('//input[@id="propertyId"]/@value').extract_first(),
            'Habitaciones': response.xpath('.//dl/dt[h3/text()="Habitaciones"]/following-sibling::dd[1]/h4/text()').extract_first(),
            'Parqueadero': response.xpath('.//dl/dt[h3/text()="Parqueadero"]/following-sibling::dd[1]/h4/text()').extract_first(),
            'Tipo de calentador': response.xpath('.//dl/dt[h3/text()="Tipo de calentador"]/following-sibling::dd[1]/h4/text()').extract_first(),
            'Cuarto de servicio': response.xpath('.//dl/dt[h3/text()="Cuarto de servicio"]/following-sibling::dd[1]/h4/text()').extract_first(),
            'Tipo de acabado piso': response.xpath('.//dl/dt[h3/text()="Tipo de acabado piso"]/following-sibling::dd[1]/h4/text()').extract_first(),
            'Area_Cons': response.xpath('.//dl/dt[h3/text()="Área construida"]/following-sibling::dd[1]/h4/text()').extract_first()
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need `dont_filter=True`. Like this

```
yield scrapy.Request(url='http://www.*********.com/search/list/ajax', method="POST", headers=headers, meta=querystring, dont_filter=True)
```

Comment: Thank you, It loops now but it doesn't extract info after the 3 iteration. Why would that happen?

Comment: Is value of href variable always different? If not, also try use dont_filter=True argument in request. Or maybe some error in selector of href.

Comment: For some weird reason the response changes after the 3 page, when I put star_url after I create the class, it works for some reason. thanks for the answer I wouldn't have figured out the don't_filter by myself :)